# Short circuit analysis

Tags: power, simulation, transmission-line, reactive-power, real-power

Im given the next distribution line with a generator and a load
[image]

The generator is set at \$23\,kV\$ the line impedance is \$9.5\Omega +j19.055\Omega\$ and the aparent power is \$1.5MW+j2MVars\$ in the load and the load voltage is the \$20.44\,kV\$ of the picture.
Now the idea is to check it for short circuit conditions, and I have been told the program can't simulate it.
So I'm guessing the load has to be disconnected/opened. If there is no load all the power is going to bus 2(I'm supposing bus 2 is grounded) but then if there is no load in bus 2 then only a small fraction of (real) power would be consumed by bus 2 and the transmission line.
Thats the correct power flow idea?
Also how can be calculated the aparent,reactive and real power of the line and the generator under these conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when we do fault calculations we ignore load flow and assume the voltage behind reactance of the generators have a flat profile (all 1.0 or 1.05pu etc).  You could also use the load flow first to find that prefault generator emf if desired for the particular load level of interest.

Depending on the time frame of interest (sub-transient, transient, or synchronous) you would use the appropriate impedance for the generator (e.g. \${X_d}'', X_d’, \text{or}\, X_d\$).

What you will find is that for three-phase faults at your load bus the only power out of the generator will be \$I^2R\$ losses in the generator windings and transmission line.  No power can be transmitted through a three-phase zero-voltage fault so nothing gets to the load.  You will find that most of what you will see is reactive power to the fault.

$$P=\frac{EVsin\theta}{X_T}$$
$$Q=\frac{E^2-EVcos\theta}{X_T}$$

Where \$E\$ is sending end voltage, \$V\$ is receiving and voltage, and \$X_T\$ is total reactance between the two buses (neglects resistance).

For a simple system like you show, the calculation for a three-phase fault is easy.  For unbalanced faults you can work by hand using symmetrical components easy enough.  Actually, since you don’t have any transformers it would be easy to just do any of these using three-phase variables.

**UPDATE**: Answering comment question about three-phase fault calculation.

In this example the voltage behind generator reactance is \$1.0\$ pu.  The machine reactance used is the subtransient \$X_d''=j0.20 pu\$ and the line impedance is \$Z=j0.1375 pu\$. This example is from my lecture notes on symmetrical components.  The three-phase fault is just as easily solved without symmet.

[image]

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing the primes.

Comment: Thanks @ErikR   :-)

Comment: @relayman357, thanks for the answer, can you direct to some examples of the three-phase fault calculation. I cant fully grasp the idea to do the calculations. I understand these system is not unbalanced.

Comment: Hi @avelardo, you are welcome.  I added an **UPDATE** to my answer showing calculation of three-phase fault current for a similar configuration.  You should be able to do the same for your data.  The fault is a bolted (zero voltage) three-phase fault at bus G, hence \$V_1=V_A=V_B=V_C=0\$ at bus G.

Comment: @relayman357, just great thanks for your kind help!

Comment: @avelardo my pleasure. You are welcome